# No extension for "Windows Machine Learning Code Generator" in vs 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, windows-machine-learning

I am looking for Windows Machine Learning Code Generator with VS 2022 supports but in market place no option available. I am able to find it for VS 2019 but nothing related to vs2022.

How to use it with vs2022 with ONNX model?

Or any workaround approach to do so.

Comment: The extension developer of the extension mentioned has to update it to make it compatible with VS 2022, hence why you can't find it for 2022.